# Не загружается thank you page после отправки данных формы через phpmailer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, phpmailer

После отправки данных через phpmailer не загружается thank-you page. Но она видна в разделе "сеть" инструментов разработчика - весь её html: http://joxi.ru/eAOednvcpRqJJm Проблема началась после того, как я подключил jquery validation для проверки формы - до этого всё работало. Письма приходят исправно, все данные формы передаются. Я пока только учусь, видимо, что-то где-то сломал, и не хватает мозгов отследить ошибку. С PHP, к сожалению, не знаком вообще никак.

Вот как я пытаюсь загружать страницу:

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Message could not be sent.  ";
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
  }
    header('location: thank-you.html')
```

Вот фрагмент с валидацией:

```
$('.popup__container').validate({
        rules: {
            field: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var formData = new FormData(form);

            $.ajax({
                url: "./mail.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('success');
                }
            });
        },
        messages: {
            yourname: {
                required: "поле не заполнено",
                maxlength: "в поле должно быть не более 50 символов"
            },
            msg: "поле не заполнено или заполнено не верно",
            yourmail: "необходимо ввести номер телефона или email"
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы здесь

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "./mail.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success');
        }
    });
```

отправляете вашу форму на сервер аяксом и после успешного выполнения запроса ничего с пришедшим результатом не делаете, просто выводите success в консоли js. Вам либо нужно отказаться от аякса, просто делать form.submit() либо оставить аякс и после получения успешного ответа, делать редирект на thank-you.html

редирект можно сделать так window.location.href = '/thank-you.html ';

Comment: Спасибо огромное, заработало! Вопрос решён!